# Ruby on Rails - bundle install is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to do `bundle install` it gives the error below.

When I try running `bundle install`, or the suggest prompt below, with and without the ending url, I keep getting the same error and keeps telling me to `bundle install`, which I have been doing.

**ERROR**

An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ubuntu, try to run

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

If you're using MAC

```
brew install postgresql
```

Then, try to run `gem install pg` again